# Adding total counts as horizontal lines to histograms in facet_grid()

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, facet

Data:

I have a data frame comprising 4 variables and about 300k rows including a unique account ID, a start date in yyyy-mm-dd, a start year, and the total number of months to-date the customer has held an account active.  Snippet of the data below (don't let the row numbers confuse, this is obviously a subset, if more data is necessary, let me know):

```
 > head(ten.by.id)
    acct.id start_date strt.yr max_ten
1       155 1998-11-01    1998     175
19      902 2001-09-01    2001     143
39      995 2001-09-01    2001     143
59     1014 2000-10-01    2000     153
78     1017 2000-04-01    2000     160
100    1137 2000-11-01    2000     153
```

Problem (Why I want to render a faceted plot):

Showing a histogram of the entire dataset across all years renders the following:

[image: Frequency histogram of Tenure by # of Customers]

Obviously, there are mixed distributions of information here, but the effect is unknown. First I thought I'd check for time domain effects with a visual. By using facets, I can provide a serial histogram of frequency distributions by year, overlaying the KDE plot for each year.

If multiple distributions were a product of something that occurred over time, I could spot check relevant shape changes (i.e. uni to multimodal). I used the code below to generate this plot:

```
maxten_time <- ggplot(ten.by.id, aes(max_ten)) 
                      + geom_histogram(colour="grey19", fill="orange", binwidth=2, stat="bin") 
                      + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,12000,by=100)) 
                      + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,180,by=45)) 
                      + labs(title ="Serial Distribution of Max Length of Tenure for all Customers by Start Date", x="Max Tenure(months)", y="# of Customers", colour="blue") 
                      + facet_grid(. ~ strt.yr) + geom_density(fill=NA, colour="orange", cex=1) + aes(y = ..count..)
```

Which renders the following:

[image]

Questions for recreating the faceted plot:

- What I wish to do is add a horizontal line (or some other single marker) to each facet which indicates
  the total # of customer starts for each year. Can this be done in a faceted
  plot?
- I would like to add an additional axis that spans across the facets to
  mark the number of months across all years (1 to 175). Am I reaching with ggplot to try to do this (i.e. since each facet is its own plot, would aligning the month markers across all facets even be possible)? I haven't seen any relevant examples on doing something quite like this.

The objective is merely to combine the horiz lines in each facet and the axis across facets into the entire plot. Any direction would be helpful.

Phillip

Comment: If you simplify you question, then you might get an answer. For example, give some simplified data, skip all unneeded ggplot code, i.e. do we really need to know about the theme?

Comment: I edited this some, and removed non-relevant code. I don't think adding more data adds any information to the problem. The objective is simply to add horizontal lines or some marker in each facet noting the sum of new customers in a particular year. The second is to add a secondary x-axis that is a marker for number of months across the entire observation period (1998 to-date, so a line marked 1 to 175). Of course, one question would be, if it can be done, how would one align the monthly markers correctly since there are breaks between facets?